# WooCommerce add admin custom field(s) to simple subscriptions

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

In WooCommerce, I have enabled [WooCommerce Subscriptions](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-subscriptions/) plugin and it's working fine as per my expectations.

However, I have a one custom requirement from client. I want to add custom field(s) while creating a product in **Variable Subscriptions** and **Simple Subscriptions**.

I have added custom field(s) in **Variable Subscriptions** using below code and it's working as per my expectations. Here is my code.

```
<?php

// Showing fields for variable subscriptions 
add_action('woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes', 'show_WC_Product_Variable_Subscription_Variation_Custom_Fields', 10, 3);

// Saving fields for variable subscriptions 
add_action('woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'save_WC_Product_Variable_Subscription_Variation_Custom_Fields', 10, 2);
    
function show_WC_Product_Variable_Subscription_Variation_Custom_Fields($loop, $variation_data, $variation) {
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(
        array(
            'id'            => "my_text_field{$loop}",
            'name'          => "my_text_field[{$loop}]",
            'value'         => get_post_meta($variation->ID, 'my_text_field', true),
            'label'         => __('Some label', 'woocommerce'),

        )
    );
}

function save_WC_Product_Variable_Subscription_Variation_Custom_Fields($variation_id, $loop) {

    if (empty($variation_id)) return;

    $text_field = $_POST['my_text_field'][$loop];
    update_post_meta($variation_id, 'my_text_field', esc_attr($text_field));
}
```

And here is how it looks like now working fine.

[image]

As you can see in screenshot above, the last field labeled as "Some label" .. my custom field added.

However, I want to add this same field which I set **Simple Subscription**. Here I mean.

[image]

As you can see, I want that same custom fields to show and save here as well ..

I have researched but yet not able to find any hook.

Can someone guide me please how can I achieve this.

Comment: Any chance to get a feed back on the answer below please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated:**

To add a custom field to Admin product data *settings* > general *tab* **on simple  subscriptions**:

```
// Showing custom fields on admin product settings "general" tab
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'add_admin_product_custom_fields', 10, 3);
function add_admin_product_custom_fields() {
    global $post;
    
    echo '<div class="product_custom_field show_if_simple show_if_subscription">';
    
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'            => 'my_text_field',
        'name'          => 'my_text_field',
        'label'         => __('Some label', 'woocommerce'),
    ) );
    
    echo '</div>';
}

// Saving custom fields values from admin product settings
add_action('woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'save_admin_product_custom_fields_values');
function save_admin_product_custom_fields_values( $product ) {
    if ( isset($_POST['my_text_field']) ) {
        $product->update_meta_data( 'my_text_field', sanitize_text_field($_POST['my_text_field']) );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

To display it on simple and variable subscriptions change:

```
echo '<div class="product_custom_field show_if_simple show_if_subscription">';
```

with:

```
echo '<div class="product_custom_field">';
```

---

Addition for a checkbox field:

```
// Showing custom fields on admin product settings "general" tab
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'add_admin_product_custom_checkbox_fields', 10, 3);
function add_admin_product_custom_checkbox_fields() {
    global $post;

    echo '<div class="product_custom_field show_if_simple show_if_subscription">';

    echo '<p><strong>' . __("Mindesk e-Commerce", 'woocommerce') . '</strong></p>';

    $value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mindesk_analytics_opt_out', true);

    woocommerce_wp_checkbox(array(
        'id'            => "mindesk_analytics_opt_out",
        'name'          => "mindesk_analytics_opt_out",
        'wrapper_class' => 'show_if_simple',
        'label'         => __('&nbsp; Analytics', 'woocommerce'),
        'value'         => $value,
    ) );

    echo '</div>';
}

// Saving custom fields values from admin product settings
add_action('woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'save_admin_product_custom_checkbox_fields_values');
function save_admin_product_custom_checkbox_fields_values( $product ) {
    $value = isset($_POST['mindesk_analytics_opt_out']) ? 'yes' : 'no';
    $product->update_meta_data('mindesk_analytics_opt_out', esc_attr($value) );
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: How you are showing the value field in `woocommerce_wp_text_input` i cant see `value` attribute here .. @LoicTheAztec

Comment: I am not getting you here `To display it on simple and variable subscriptions change:

` what you mean by that .. as you previously answered my question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66023181/6829420

Comment: I want that same field to show in "Simple Subscription" .. is it possible to show with only one hook or do i need to use different hooks which you mentioned in this answer and that answer ..

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave The function `woocommerce_wp_text_input()` handle that so no need to add 'value' attribute like for variations… You just need 'value' attribute for variations or in some other cases…

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave This is for simple subscriptions.

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave I have added an addition to handle a checkbox field for simple subscriptions

Comment: I have one question though .. u have used here `update_meta_data` cant we use `update_post_meta` just like we used for variable subscriptions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66022677/woocommerce-variable-subscription-custom-field-checkbox-set-default-as-unchecked @LoicTheAztec ?

Comment: by the way .. your code is showing even in `simple product` option as well .. i dont want to show there

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave Since WooCommerce 3 there are some new hooks and methods to be used instead of old WordPress way with `update_post_meta`, as woocommerce will migrate in future all custom posts and postmeta to custom tables… You can remove `show_if_simple` and keep `show_if_subscription` to only display that field on simple subscriptions.