# Woocommerce variable subscription custom field checkbox set default as unchecked

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, custom-fields, woocommerce-subscriptions

Below is my code in which I have set a custom field called `mindesk_analytics_opt_out` for my **Variable Subscriptions** and it's working fine as per my expectations.

However, Whenever I create a new variation and open the panel, my default checkbox always set as `checked`. I cant understand where I have done wrong here in my code.

Can someone guide me please where I made a small mistake? Here is my working code.

```
<?php

// Showing fields for variable subscriptions 
add_action('woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes', 'show_WC_Product_Variable_Subscription_Variation_Custom_Fields', 10, 3);

// Saving fields for variable subscriptions 
add_action('woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'save_WC_Product_Variable_Subscription_Variation_Custom_Fields', 10, 2);


function show_WC_Product_Variable_Subscription_Variation_Custom_Fields($loop, $variation_data, $variation) {

    $mindesk_analytics_opt_out = get_post_meta($variation->ID, 'mindesk_analytics_opt_out', true);
    echo '<strong>Mindesk e-Commerce</strong>';

    woocommerce_wp_checkbox(
        array(
            'id'            => "mindesk_analytics_opt_out{$loop}",
            'name'          => "mindesk_analytics_opt_out[{$loop}]",
            'wrapper_class' => 'show_if_simple',
            'label'         => __('&nbsp; Analytics', 'woocommerce'),
            'value'         => !empty($mindesk_analytics_opt_out) ? 'yes' : $mindesk_analytics_opt_out,
            'cbvalue'       => $mindesk_analytics_opt_out,

        )
    );
}
function save_WC_Product_Variable_Subscription_Variation_Custom_Fields($variation_id, $loop) {

    $mindesk_analytics_opt_out = isset($_POST['mindesk_analytics_opt_out'][$loop]) ? 'yes' : 'no';
    update_post_meta($variation_id, 'mindesk_analytics_opt_out', esc_attr($mindesk_analytics_opt_out));
}
```

Any advice or suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated:** Instead use the following function replacement *(checkbox will be unchecked by default)*

```
// Add custom field checkbox for variable subscriptions 
add_action('woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes', 'show_WC_Product_Variable_Subscription_Variation_Custom_Fields', 10, 3);
function show_WC_Product_Variable_Subscription_Variation_Custom_Fields($loop, $variation_data, $variation) {
    echo '<strong>' . __("Mindesk e-Commerce", 'woocommerce') . '</strong>';

    $value = get_post_meta($variation->ID, 'mindesk_analytics_opt_out', true);

    woocommerce_wp_checkbox(array(
        'id'            => "mindesk_analytics_opt_out{$loop}",
        'name'          => "mindesk_analytics_opt_out[{$loop}]",
        'wrapper_class' => 'show_if_simple',
        'label'         => __('&nbsp; Analytics', 'woocommerce'),
        'value'         => $value,
    ) );
}
```

Tested and works

---

This part doesn't need changes:

```
// Saving fields for variable subscriptions 
add_action('woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'save_WC_Product_Variable_Subscription_Variation_Custom_Fields', 10, 2);
function save_WC_Product_Variable_Subscription_Variation_Custom_Fields($variation_id, $loop) 
{
    $value = isset($_POST['mindesk_analytics_opt_out'][$loop]) ? 'yes' : 'no';
    update_post_meta( $variation_id, 'mindesk_analytics_opt_out', esc_attr($value) );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply .. but unfortunately .. it doesnt work .. i want default checkboxes as unchecked .. currently its checked .. i have replaced your code but still same

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave Updated sorry, I didn't catch that before.

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave I have also answered your other question, waiting for your feedback.

Comment: Thanks .. its working .. I want this same field to show in "Simple Subscription" and I asked here in which you replied .. but i m confused .. can u please reply there .. 

Thanks

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave I have added an addition with a checkbox for simple subscriptions on this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66021847/3730754